# How to disable a Laptop's Native Monitor via Command Line - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, monitor, tv

In Ubuntu 18.04, how can I disable a laptop's native monitor completely, using only the command line, in a manner where the laptop will only use an external monitor exclusively?

**Background:**

My uncle's laptop's screen went out a few years back, and after buying him a new laptop, I repurposed that old laptop (with the bad screen) to be a computer that hooks up to my TV (which does have a working screen) and I operate it with a remote keyboard that has a touch pad.

This laptop was running Ubuntu 16.04 (my favorite desktop of all time), but because 16.04 is about to lose support, this morning I upgraded it to 18.04.

On 16.04, I had the displays set up where, after login, Ubuntu 16.04 would simply turn off the laptop's native monitor (since it won't display anything but a faded white canvas anyway), and instead it would just exclusively use the TV as its primary monitor exclusively. That setup worked great.

However, after upgrading to 18.04, I cannot even login, because the login screen is only trying to display on the monitor that doesn't work. I think I may have logged in once (blindly), but all I ever saw (on the screen that does work) is the mouse-pointer. I cannot reach the settings screen where I may be able to turn off the bad monitor again (and only use the TV as the monitor - like before).

The only thing I'm able to do, in this new setup, is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (I think it was) and this will display a command prompt on the TV.

**From there, how can I configure the display settings so that the bad monitor is just turned off, and the TV's monitor is used exclusively?**

Comment: [Issue 1376](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1376)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xrandr to do that.

Without argument it gives you something like that:

> Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 3840 x 975, maximum 8192 x 8192
> Virtual1 connected primary 1920x929+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
> 1920x929      60.00*+
> 2560x1600     59.99
> 1920x1440     60.00
> 1856x1392     60.00
> 1792x1344     60.00
> 1920x1200     59.88
> 1600x1200     60.00
> 1680x1050     59.95
> 1400x1050     59.98
> 1280x1024     60.02
> 1440x900      59.89
> 1280x960      60.00
> 1360x768      60.02
> 1152x864      75.00
> 1280x768      59.87
> 1024x768      60.00
> 800x600       60.32
> 640x480       59.94
> Virtual2 connected 1920x975+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
> 1920x975      60.00*+
> 2560x1600     59.99
> 1920x1440     60.00
> 1856x1392     60.00
> 1792x1344     60.00
> 1920x1200     59.88
> 1600x1200     60.00
> 1680x1050     59.95
> 1400x1050     59.98
> 1440x900      59.89
> 1280x960      60.00
> 1360x768      60.02
> 1280x800      59.81
> 1152x864      75.00
> 1280x768      59.87
> 1024x768      60.00
> 800x600       60.32
> 640x480       59.94

Virtual1 and Virtual2 are the monitor names, these may differ for you.
In this example to disable Virtual2 the command would be:

> xrandr --output Virtual2 --off

Comment: Will that setting survive a reboot? Remember, I'm typing ctrl-alt-F2 in order to see a command prompt on my TV (which completely takes me out of GNOME). If I reboot after a command like `xrandr --output Virtual2 --off`, will the GNOME login display on my TV instead of my bad monitor? Or must I know some other command to go back into GNOME without rebooting?

Comment: No, it won't survive a reboot. I guess if your display manager provides a way to execute commands before user login it should work.

Here is described how to do that for GDM amongst others: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux

Comment: That `xrandr` command doesn't work after `ctrl-alt-f2` in Ubuntu 18.04. However, after a blind login and `ctrl-alt-t` it does work. Ultimately, after a blind login, I hit the `super key` and typed `system settings` and pressed `enter`. After that I was able to configure the display settings via the GUI. Only remaining issue is that I always have to do a blind login. GNOME development didn't have enough forethought to anticipate my situation. In 16.04 Unity, the login appears on any monitor you move the mouse-pointer to. Default should be to show login on all connected displays in mirror mode!

Comment: [Issue 1376](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1376)

Comment: I know that lightdm login screen follows the mouse. Alternative idea to try would be to disconnect the laptops monitor from the mainboard. I guess this way it should default to your external monitor.

Comment: I thought about that and I've been meaning to try it. Still, the software should be able to accommodate me in the meantime. They need to make it more accommodating for such scenarios in my opinion.